# Why do we add a vovel "a" in the word "kitab" in arabic? Alif is already there

Tags: arabic

Screenshot from a book that confuses me. Why fatha is between ta and alif?

Thank you!

[image: screenshot from a book that confuses me]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Convention, really.

You're right that a medial alif with no diacritics unambiguously means *ā*. However, some books like to use harakat "fully"—that is, putting a vowel marker or sukun on every single consonant—and in this tradition, the long vowels *ā ī ū* are written fathah-alif, kasrah-ya', dammah-waw.

Is it strictly necessary? Not at all; you could get rid of all sukun and all harakat before long vowels without introducing any ambiguity. But if you ask most Arabic-speakers, harakat *in general* aren't strictly necessary, and people get by just fine without them. They're mostly used in religious texts and texts for language-learners, and in those contexts, the additional clarity is considered to be worth the extra ink.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you!

Comment: I'm actually confused by the use of vowel diacritics in Arabic. I also thought they were not normally used, but then an Egyptian fellow I know says they are used in virtually every modern thing, including digital communication if I understood him correctly. May also vary depending on the country, I guess...

Comment: Much the same thing (mutatis mutandis) can be said about Masoretic vowel points in Hebrew. Modern Hebrew writers rarely use them, but they're always available.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional Arabic grammar analyses the phoneme /a:/ as the ḥarika “fatḥ” followed by ʼalif sākina. This is fully reflected by the vocalised spelling.

Answer (score 0):

If you omit sukun and harakat, you cannot correctly read رأس or
تأشيرة. Of course, native speakers don't need that help.

Comment: There are no native speakers of al-ʽarabiyya al-fuṣḥā. It is learnt in school.